# how to search and get herf's value

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web

```
<a class="wiki-link-external" href="http://example.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener" title="http://example.com">
```

I want to get http://example.com

I tried

```
img = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.wiki-link-external')

print(len(img))

for a in img:
    print(a.get_attribute('herf'))
```

but only get [] and 1 ...

Comment: Could you post more code to debug? And by the way, it is `href`, not `herf`..that's what you typed in your print statement

Answer (score 0):

```
img = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.wiki-link-external')

print(len(img))

for a in img:
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

**href** not ***herf***